# How to display Mile stone tracker in record detail page

Tags: case, casemilestone, entitlements, service, template

we are going to setup entitlement process in our org.we created templates as well as Entitlement and milestones.

But now as per standard we are able to display milestone tracker in case feed page.

But we want to display in directly case detail page.Because my support team mostly working on detail page.

I'm able to include it in pagelayout through inline pages.But only one issue is unable to display in it properly.Mile stone tracker icon & mile stone name is displaying not properly.Because i tried but i am unable to find to display in middle of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you have Case feed based page layout.

You cannot put Milestone component in the case details page unless you create a visualforce page to embed that using `<apex:milestoneTracker>`. Refer [Set Up the Milestone Tracker](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestone_tracker.htm&type=0)

If you are using console application and corresponding page layout then you can leverage sidebar console component.

[image: Milestone tracker]

To add this component, go to page layout, choose `Custom Console Components` link and define configuration like this:

[image: sidebar]

Comment: I updated my question only display issue is there any way to resolve or hide mile stone name in pagelayout.